# Javascript - Como validar campos de um formulário

Tags: javascript

> Estou criando um formulário o qual preciso validar: **E-mail, CPF, Data de Nacimento, Telefone para Contato, Telefone Opcional**.

Alguém sabe como fazer isso com aquela "máscara", que quando a pessoa digita a data por exemplo, não necessita inserir as "/" barras, o javascript faz isso. Assim como nos outros campos que citei?

Outra coisa, nos outros campos como **Nome, Endereço, etc...**, se não forem inserido os dados, emite um alerta pedindo para que seja inserido.

**Exemplo:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Observação: Javascript Puro.....

Comment: Você está pedindo muita coisa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você pode utilizar uma biblioteca externa chamada [Lightweight Pure JavaScript](https://github.com/grokmann/JsInputMask) o nome ja diz tudo.

**Utilização Básica**

Importar o arquivo

```
<script src="input-mask.js" ></script>
```

Exemplo de aplicação para o campo Data

```
new InputMask().Initialize(document.querySelectorAll("#date"),{
  mask: InputMaskDefaultMask.Date, 
  placeHolder: "Date: 01/01/2015" 
});
```

Na biblioteca você irá encontrar mais exemplos como a de validação de telefone e Social Security Number (SSN)(como a identidade aqui no brasil) você pode realizar a leitura dos exemplos e aplicar em sua página da forma que deseja.

Você pode visualizar esta biblioteca externa funcionando [aqui](http://www.cssscript.com/demo/lightweight-pure-javascript-input-mask/).

Clique [aqui](http://www.cssscript.com/lightweight-pure-javascript-input-mask/) para visualizar a Fonte.

Comment: Ainda não é a resposta que espero. :(

Comment: @AlexandreLopes o que posso fazer para melhorar minha resposta ?

Comment: Tá tudo muito complexo. Era pra ser tão simples :'(

Comment: Alexandre.. mais simples do que já te responderam seria alguém fazer o seu trabalho..

Answer (score 11):

Você pode utilizar o [jQuery Mask](https://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) para realizar as formatações do input:
O código ficará assim:

```
 $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
 $('.date').mask('00/00/0000');
 $('.phone_with_ddd').mask('(00) 0000-00000');
```

E para a validação você poderá usar a validação HTML5 ou utilizar um plugin para isso, tal como o [Parsley](http://parsleyjs.org/).

Quando você tiver dúvidas mais formadas e não tão genéricas assim, abra uma nova pergunta específica.

Comment: Amigo, gostaria de fazer utilizando javascript puro. É possível?

Comment: Recomendo que você utilize um plugin para isso, sei que temos como premissa fazer tudo para garantir a estabilidade. Mas tenha em mente que usando um plugin você já vai ter resolvido problemas que outras pessoas da comunidade passaram e contribuiram em um projeto para que outras pessoas não passem. No caso de masks, existem muitos problemas de compatibilidade principalmente em mobile.

Comment: Vou fazer uns testes. :)

Comment: Amigo, e desse `Parsley`, como ficaria o código?

Comment: A implementação do Parsley é bem complexa, recomendo que você leia a documentação dele e dê uma olhada no exemplo: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html#

Comment: Pior que não sou muito bom com JS, muito menos com jQuery. Essa parece ser uma alternativa não muito viável pra mim.

Comment: Você poderia utilizar a validação do HTML5, colocando o `required` porém, você não vai conseguir deixar a validação correta, mas no caso do required irá funcionar em navegadores novos, exceto IE8. O que pode gerar spam com formulários incompletos.

Comment: Não amigo, não é um formulário de contato.

Comment: Amigo pra usar esse plugin jQuery Mask, eu puxo ele de onde?

Comment: Você pode utilizar um gerenciador de dependências ou baixar do github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/master/dist/jquery.mask.min.js

Comment: +100 pra você amigo!