# Recebo emails fantasmas antes do email de teste

Tags: php, html, formulário

Tenho enfrentado um problema curioso. Elaborei um formulário básico em `php` apenas para enviar e-mail pelo site. Porém estou realizando alguns testes no serviço de hospedagem e tenho recebido vários e-mails fantasmas antes do e-mail de teste.

Já pesquisei para ver se é alguma coisa errada com o código, mas acredito que por mais básico que seja, esteja ok. Alguém consegue me dar uma luz?

```
<?php
    $msg=0;
    @$msg= $_POST['msg'];?> 

`<section class="form">
    <?php if($msg=="enviado"): ?>
        <h3>Mensagem enviada. Agradecemos seu contato!</h3>
    <?php else: ?>
        <form class="contact-form" action="contactForm.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nome completo">
            <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail">
            <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="Telefone">
            <input type="text" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Sua empresa">
            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Assunto">
            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Deixe aqui sua mensagem!"></textarea>
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    <?php endif; ?>
</section>`

<?php
    $para= "juliano.eibel@live.com";
    $assunto="Contato pelo Site.";
    $name= $_POST['name'];
    $mail= $_POST['mail'];
    $telephone= $_POST['telephone'];
    $company= $_POST['company'];
    $subject= $_POST['subject'];
    $msg= $_POST['message'];

    $corpo= "<strong>Mensagem de contato!</strong><br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong>Nome: </strong> $name<br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong>E-mail: </strong> $mail<br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong>Telefone: </strong> $telephone<br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong>Empresa: </strong> $company<br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong>Assunto: </strong> $subject<br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong>Mensagem: </strong> $msg";

    $header="Content-Type: text/html; charset= utf-8\n";
    $header .="From: $mail Reply-to: $mail\n";

    mail($para,$assunto,$corpo,$header);

    header("location:index.php?msg=enviado");?>
```

Comment: duvida já pensou em usar um framework como   o codeingiter?
Te resolveria um monte de aspectos

Comment: O que seriam esses "emails fantasmas"?

Comment: Não é porque a função mail sempre sera executada, mesmo não clicando em enviar? Acho que tem que ter uma condição antes.

Comment: @igorhenrique não, porque os e-mails fantasmas aparecem junto com o e-mail de teste após clicar no Enviar.

Comment: @dvd Quando clico em Enviar para um e-mail de teste, recebo em minha caixa de entrada o e-mail certinho com Nome, Asssunto, Email, etc preenchido conforme foi enviado. Porém junto com o e-mail de teste chegam dois e-mails fantasmas, sem conteúdo nenhum preenchido.

Comment: Qual chega primeiro o email preenchido ou o vazio?

Comment: @RpgBoss geralmente chegam os dois vazios antes. Tem vezes que vem dois vazios e dois de teste iguais.

Comment: esta usando sendmail?

Comment: @igorhenrique não, apenas a função mail do php.

Comment: Por que não utilizar o Php Mailer (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu acredito que quando você abre a página um e-mail já foi enviado, quando aperta enviar ele manda um preenchido, assim totalizando dois.

Isso por que sua `IF` está confusa para o código, inclusive por conta deste redirecionamento sendo que no código que você postou existem duas páginas, o **index.php** e o **contatcForm.php**, o que provavelmente gera mais um e-mail em branco.

O que deu impressão com aquele começo colocando 0 (ZERO) na variável que você usava outra linguagem de programação que necessita declarar variáveis no começo do código, essa parte vai ser desnecessária.

Vou deixar o método correto aqui, mas você vai precisar aprender o básico sobre PHP e lógica antes de tentar criar mais sistemas com PHP.

Por enquanto este vai funcionar, mas você vai ter que criar um validador pra obrigar o usuário a preencher os campos.

**[formulário-de-cadastro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/275299/formul%C3%A1rio-de-cadastro)**

E depois se quiser validar e-mail, telefone, etc pode usar *expressão regular*:

**[javascript-como-validar-campos-de-um-formulário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148242/javascript-como-validar-campos-de-um-formul%C3%A1rio)**

Agora vamos ao HTML e PHP.

---

Este vai ser o **index.php**:

```
<section class="form">
<?php
if(isset($_GET['msg']) && $_GET['msg'] === "enviado"){
    echo "      <h3><h3>Mensagem enviada. Agradecemos seu contato!</h3>\n";
}
?>
    <form class="contact-form" action="contactForm.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Nome completo">
        <input type="text" id="mail" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail">
        <input type="text" id="telephone" name="telephone" placeholder="Telefone">
        <input type="text" id="company" name="company" placeholder="Sua empresa">
        <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Assunto">
        <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Deixe aqui sua mensagem!"></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

---

Este vai ser o **contactForm.php**:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $corpo= "<strong>Mensagem de contato!</strong><br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong>Nome: </strong> ".$_POST['name']."<br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong>E-mail: </strong> ".$_POST['mail']."<br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong>Telefone: </strong> ".$_POST['telephone']."<br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong>Empresa: </strong> ".$_POST['company']."<br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong>Assunto: </strong> ".$_POST['subject']."<br><br>";
    $corpo .= "<strong>Mensagem: </strong> ".$_POST['message'];

    $header="Content-Type: text/html; charset= utf-8\n";
    $header .="From: ".$_POST['mail']." Reply-to: ".$_POST['mail']."\n";
    mail("juliano.eibel@live.com","Contato pelo Site.",$corpo,$header);
    header("location:index.php?msg=enviado");
}else{
    header("location:index.php");
}
?>
```